# Remove white space from a data frame column and add path

Tags: r

I have a column of a dataframe with data like this:

```
df$names
"stock 1"
"stock stock1 2"
"stock 2"
```

I would like to remove the spaces of everyrow of text. A result like this:

```
df$names
"stock1"
"stockstock12"
"stock2"
```

And add a path for the name of files and have a final column like this (the path is the same for all rows)

```
df$names
"C:/Desktop/stock_files/stock1"
"C:/Desktop/stock_files/stockstock12"
"C:/Desktop/stock_files/stock2"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to remove the white space.  We select one or more spaces (`\\s+`) and replace it with `''`.

```
 df$names <- gsub('\\s+', '', df$names)
 df$names
 #[1] "stock1"       "stockstock12" "stock2"
```

Then, we use `paste` to join the strings together

```
  path <- "C:/Desktop/stock_files"
  df$names <- paste(path, df$names, sep="/")
  df$names
  #[1] "C:/Desktop/stock_files/stock1"       "C:/Desktop/stock_files/stockstock12"
  #[3] "C:/Desktop/stock_files/stock2"
```

Comment: Special reason why not recommending `file.path` function?

Comment: @drmariod There is no reason except that `paste` came to my mind first.  You could post that as an answer as it is more preferred.